# Switch color of black and white image with css / js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wonder if some of you know how to do something like this, in the part that says "swatches".

http://designmodo.com/flat/

They have this image:

[image]

and when you click an icon, it turns the color the icon is.
This mean a lot of space saved from having multiple images with diferent colors.
If someone knows how to make this effect, even with irregular images, please tell me in the comments!

Oh, and if you know how to do it with jquery, even better (i'm not so familiarized with js)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/e3xPL/

Comment: soo, it's that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original image is a transparent png. You can set the background color of the image to change the color like this: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Nf53/)

### HTML

```
<img id="present" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPyIe.png" width="200">
<ul>
    <li>
        <button type="button" data-color="red">red</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type="button" data-color="blue">blue</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type="button" data-color="green">green</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type="button" data-color="orange">orange</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Javascript

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('#present').css('background-color', $(this).data('color'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a transparent image and they just change the background color .

http://designmodo.com/wp-content/themes/designmodov2.1/flat-ui/images/img-4.png